# flutter pub get command in new project get me the all packages of old project

Tags: android, flutter, dart, caching, dependencies

this is my pubsec.yaml dependencies i only need one package

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
   sdk: flutter



 cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
 native_notify: ^0.0.17
```

my pub get give me this

```
flutter pub get
Resolving dependencies...
 awesome_notifications 0.6.21 (0.7.4+1 available)
 collection 1.17.1 (1.18.0 available)
 file 6.1.4 (7.0.0 available)
 firebase_core 1.24.0 (2.15.0 available)
  firebase_core_web 1.7.3 (2.6.0 available)
 firebase_messaging 11.4.4 (14.6.5 available)
firebase_messaging_platform_interface 3.5.4 (4.5.4 available)
firebase_messaging_web 2.4.4 (3.5.4 available)
 http 0.13.6 (1.1.0 available)
 intl 0.17.0 (0.18.1 available)
 matcher 0.12.15 (0.12.16 available)
 material_color_utilities 0.2.0 (0.8.0 available)
 source_span 1.9.1 (1.10.0 available)
 stack_trace 1.11.0 (1.11.1 available)
 stream_channel 2.1.1 (2.1.2 available)
 test_api 0.5.1 (0.6.1 available)
 Got dependencies!
```

i make cache clean but i get same problem

Answer (score 0):

Those are just basic packages Flutter needs and some of them might be packages native_notify might depend upon